# expectation of unbounded functions

Tags: integration, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega, A, \mathbb{P} )$ be a probability space. Let $f: \Omega  \rightarrow [-\infty, \infty]$ an $A$-measurable function.

If $f$ is bounded on the positive side and unbounded on the negative side. Is it possible that $\mathbb{E}[f]$ (the expectation with probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ ) is finite?

and what if $f$ is unbounded on the 2 sides ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a strong example. Let $\Omega = [0,1]$, and $\mathcal{A}$ is the Borel sigma algebra. Consider $P$ to be Lebesgue measure on $\Omega$. Define

$f(\omega)=
  \begin{cases}
   q & \text{if } \omega = \frac{p}{q} \text{ in reduced form and $q$ is odd} \\
   -q &\text{if } \omega = \frac{p}{q} \text{ in reduced form and $q$ is even}\\
   0 & \text{if } \omega \text{ is irrational}
  \end{cases}$

Then $f$ has finite expectation $0$, but $f$ is unbounded from above and below on **every** interval.

(Note: The reason why $f$ is measurable is that the pre-image of $(a, \infty)$ is countable or co-countable for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$, and such sets are clearly Borel)

Comment: thanks (it is really a nice example)

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, possibly. As for your second question. Yes, it can be finite, most symetric distributions are examples of this. The measure is bounded, but the space can be infinite.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f$ can be unbounded and still be integrable. For example, $f\left(x\right)=\exp\left(-x^{2}\right)\mathtt{1}_{\mathbb{R}_{+}}\left(x\right)
 +\delta_{-1}\left(x\right)$ defines an unbounded function, but $\mathbb{E}\left[f\right]=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ for the Lebesgue's measure (with $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$). Here, you notice that $f$ is actually bounded Lebesgue-almost everywhere.

Comment: what is meant by the function $\delta_{-1}(x)$ ?

Comment: you take the Lebesgue measure (let's say $L$) on $\mathbb{R}$ but $L(\mathbb{R}) = \infty$ and we said we work on a probability space and what is meant by $\delta_{-1}$?

Comment: Oh yes, I am sorry for the choice of the measure. Lebesgue's measure is a measure of probability if taken on an interval $\left(a,a+1\right)$ with $a$ a real number (the interval can be open or closed). $\delta_{-1}$ is the delta Dirac measure (or distribution) defined by $\delta_{-1}\left(A\right)=\mathtt{1}_{A}\left(-1\right)$ for any measurable set $A$. The important thing here is that you can allow some values as infinity on negligible sets (for your measure) without changing the expectation.